# How can I parse my json file from asset in kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

How can I parse my json file in kotlin. There are many solution for this on the internet but all of them are same however I couldnt find to parse my json file in kotlin.

**my json file**

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "collocation": "above average",
            "meaning": "more than average, esp. in amount, age, height, weight etc. "
        },
        {
            "collocation": "absolutely necessary",
            "meaning": "totally or completely necessary"
        },
        {
            "collocation": "abuse drugs",
            "meaning": "to use drugs in a way that's harmful to yourself or others"
        },
        {
            "collocation": "abuse of power",
            "meaning": "the harmful or unethical use of power"
        }
    ],
    "B": [
        {
            "collocation": "back pay",
            "meaning": "money a worker earned in the past but hasn't been paid yet  "
        },
        {
            "collocation": "back road",
            "meaning": "a small country road "
        },
        {
            "collocation": "back street",
            "meaning": "a street in a town or city that's away from major roads or central areas"
        },
        {
            "collocation": "back taxes",
            "meaning": "taxes that weren't paid when they were due"
        },
        {
            "collocation": "bad breath",
            "meaning": "breath that doesn't smell nice"
        }],
```

this way it goes up to the letter **W**.

I want to parse them all by letter.

**my data classes**

```
data class Collocations(

    val tag:String,
    val collocation: List<Collocation>

)
data class Collocation(
    val collocation: String,
    val meaning: String
)
```

But I think these data classes are not correct in my opinion or not effective.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need the `Collocation` class that you provided here. Then the top-level object could be a `Map<String, List<Collocation>>` so that the letters are dynamic keys instead.

Using Kotlinx Serialization, it could look like this:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
data class Collocation(
    val collocation: String,
    val meaning: String,
)

fun main() {
    val json: String = TODO("get your JSON string here")
    val collocations = Json.decodeFromString<Map<String, List<Collocation>>>(json)

    val collocationsForA = collocations["A"]
    println(collocationsForA)
}
```

Comment: can you show code snippet ?

Comment: can you show code snippet ? so as I understand from you said Collocations class just has Map<String,List<Collocation>> and hasnt tag and collocation also Collocation data class will stay the same. right ?

Comment: @NewPartizal the code depends on the serialization library you're using. Which one is it? Kotlinx serialization?

Comment: I dont use any serialization library right know because I couldnt  understand the logic. But if we assume that I use kotlinx serialization, how can I do what you said. By the way which serialization library do you think is better to use ?

Comment: I would advise Kotlinx Serialization. It's a good option, because it is an official library meant for Kotlin. It handles Kotlin constructs out of the box, like sealed classes and the likes, and generates serializers at compile-time which is nice (IMO). Jackson with the Kotlin module is also a good option because it's very popular. Gson is not great for Kotlin, and also it's oudated (not really actively developed), and if you go that route you should prefer Moshi (its successor).

Comment: I applied it to my code as you said, but I ran into a problem. The problem is "kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead
    JSON input: collocations.json" what's wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a JSON that looks like the one in the question? It's looking for a `{`, but it seems it reaches the end of the file unexpectedly (EOF). How are you reading the file and passing the JSON?